# Re attach tab content after i've detached on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to detach some of my tabs content on pageload. I do not have access to edit the existing tab script btw. I can only add jquery after tabs are loaded.

I've done that successfully...

```
 $(document).ready ( function(){ 
  $('#tabcontent1,#tabcontent2,#tabcontent3,#tabcontent4').detach();
 });
```

But i'm trying to re attach them as needed , here is HTML

```
<div id="hometabs">
 <ul id="tabs">      
  <li class="" id="tab0" title="" onclick="javascript:show_tab('0');"><a>Tab0</a></li>      
  <li class="" id="tab1" title="" onclick="javascript:show_tab('1');"><a>Tab1</a></li>      
  <li class="" id="tab2" title="" onclick="javascript:show_tab('2');"><a>Tab2</a></li>      
  <li class="" id="tab3" title="" onclick="javascript:show_tab('3');"><a>Tab3</a></li>      
  <li class="" id="tab4" title="" onclick="javascript:show_tab('4');"><a>Tab4</a></li>
 </ul>    
</div>


<div style="" id="tabcontent0" class="homepagetabcontent">CONTENT</div>
<div style="" id="tabcontent1" class="homepagetabcontent">CONTENT</div>
<div style="" id="tabcontent2" class="homepagetabcontent">CONTENT</div>
<div style="" id="tabcontent3" class="homepagetabcontent">CONTENT</div>
<div style="" id="tabcontent4" class="homepagetabcontent">CONTENT</div>
```

When i click on Tab1 , i'd like to add back #tabcontent1 , and then click Tab2 and re attach #tabcontent2 and so on....read some tuts , tried a few things , but haven't gotten anything to work.TIA

Here is the show_tab function , which i do not have access to alter

```
function show_tab (tab_id) {

   var done = false;
   var counter = 0;
   while (! done) {
      var this_tab_content = document.getElementById("tabcontent" + counter);
      var this_tab = document.getElementById("tab" + counter);
      if (! this_tab_content) {
         done = true;
      } else {
         if (counter == tab_id) {
            this_tab_content.style.display = '';
            this_tab.className = "currenttab";
         } else {
            this_tab_content.style.display = 'none';
            this_tab.className = "";
         }
      }
      counter++;
   }
   location.hash = tab_id;
}
```

Comment: Show your show_tab() code.

Comment: added the show_tab function Chrone

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get this working

```
   var mfltab1 = $('#tabcontent1 #homepagecolumns').detach();
    $('li#tab1').one('click',function(){
       $('#tabcontent1').append(mfltab1);
    });
```